# C non-standard libraries

Tags: c

I'm quite new to programming, and I was wondering if there is a good source of well-programmed non-standard C code and libraries.

I Googled and didn't find anything. 
I was a bit surprised by this, especially because I used to search for many Python examples and libraries and never had trouble finding anything.

I already use standard libraries such as stdio.c, stdlib.c, and math.c, but I want to use some more specific C modules. A graph processing library, for example. (I don't really need this one, just a collection of C, not C++ or C#, resources and examples)

Comment: The "libraries" you refer to as "stdio.c", "stdlib.c" and "math.c" don't exist. You might mean the standard headers of <stdio.h>, <stdlib.h> and <math.h>. Including these headers provides the necessary prototypes to use certain functions, macros, et cetera in the C standard library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is no "centralized" source for C libraries... at least nothing along the lines of CPAN for Perl or the Python Package Index for Python.

Since C is sort of the "default" language for systems programming, it's often unstated that libraries are written for C.  You may want to try Freshmeat.net's [Advanced Search](http://freshmeat.net/search/set-advanced/?q=%2Bgraph&section=projects&orderby=), since it's centered on Unix software, and there are a lot of C libraries posted there.  For example, here's what I come up with searching for "graph library": http://freshmeat.net/search/?section=projects&q=%2Bgraph+%2Blibrary, and you can filter those results by language, license, etc.

(And your English is quite fine!  Which I can't say about all the posters on here :-p)

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a good repository of C code to examine and learn from then I recommend the [GNU](http://directory.fsf.org/GNU/) stuff. You can find anything from small programs like [cat](http://directory.fsf.org/project/coreutils/) to extremely large projects like [Emacs](http://directory.fsf.org/project/emacs/) and [Gnome](http://directory.fsf.org/project/gnome/). All the code is released under the GPL and can be freely incorporated into GPL'd free software.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any C specific collections of modules. If I were looking for C modules, I'd check [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) and [freshmeat](http://freshmeat.net/). [Glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/) is a fantastic library, too.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider the book [Numerical Recipes in C++](http://www.nr.com/) or the older Numerical Recipes in C (it might be out of print, though), depending on your algorithmic needs.

[EDIT] I didn't originally see this, but I found a link to the older book [here](http://www.nrbook.com/a/bookcpdf.php).